# How to display information about the Packer build at its beginning

Tags: devops, packer, infrastructure-as-code, hashicorp

I'm currently refactoring old Packer code, switching from JSON config files with a bunch of shell scripts to HCL files using its features (like default variables values, expressions...).

With my old code, I initialized most of the internal variables inside the shell script, and I also use it to display a message containing all those variables just before the Packer build itself.

Now, I'm migrating to HCL code *(which I think would be easier to maintain than the previous shell)* but I miss the idea of displaying a message with at-runtime-user-defined computed or variables/locals.

I'm currently trying to do that with a `shell` or `shell-local` provisioner, but even if I succeed this message will still appears in the middle or the end of the build, not before *(in my case the boot on Debian ISO and OS installation is still done before)*.

Does any one have an idea how to do it?

Comment: This should work the same between your old templates and your new templates. A wrapper script that inputs variable values to the `packer` command and outputs messages would not require changes for a JSON-->HCL2 migration. Could you share why this is different?

Comment: This is not different, it already works with just JSON->HCL migration but now I want to make the most of the features HCL brings and get rid of complicated bash scripts.